# Slow rendering (during scroll) on ios (tested on ipad mini)

Tags: ios, css, angularjs, ipad

I am facing some rendering issues with a web application I am developing.

It's displaying a grid of images. This has been tested to work fine on all desktop browsers - windows, mac, linux, all mobile browsers - android, iphone & a few major android tablets. I have this problem only on ipad mini.

When i scroll through the screen, there are brief periods of slices going completely white and then they get rendered (with some delay). If I scroll up the same thing happens again. Feels like some browser optimization.

Tried searching for this problem and looks like a few people have faced this. The problem I am facing is exactly as posted in this youtube link: https://youtu.be/ABp8vXtBQCw.

My ipad is running on version 11.3.1. This happens both on safari and chrome.

Few other websites I noticed having the same problem: pinterest, instagram, cnn, nytimes (magnitude varies, but can notice the problem). However I do not notice the problem with houzz.com which has as many images but still loads perfectly fine without any lags.

I am not exactly sure what exactly causes this - images, positions, etc. Has anyone come across this and know what this is? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There can be lots of reasons. I have recently had the same issue since I was loading images as background-images for canvas/figure elements. If you don't do it you can try loading all the assets at the page load and then see if it's slow rendering or loading :)

Comment: I too was loading them as background image. But now I've tried removing all that. In fact I've just removed all the images leaving behind just their containers with no luck :(. What I'm noticing is upto a certain height, it's all fine. Beyond that, this starts. Thanks for your suggestions.